# Dataflow use cases - Parallel file processing

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I am just starting out with GCP so apologies with the newbie question.

I currently have thousands of json files that need to be processed and loaded back to cloud storage (and potentially BigQuery). At the moment we do this with a Python application running on compute engine.

The files do not need to be grouped or aggregated, and only need to be processed individually (add timestamps, ordering entries, adding newlines for BigQuery, etc). I just want some way of easily parallelising this process, rather than dealing with Python subprocesses and/or spinning up more machines. 
Is this a good use case for Dataflow? If so, am I better off considering this as a streaming solution and sending all the files to Pub/Sub? Or consider it as a batch issue?

Any help/opinions welcome.

Thanks,
b/

Comment: where are your JSON files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a good use case. Dataflow is well-suited for these ETL-type jobs.

How are these json files being written/modified? If the files are being written infrequently, or are static, this is a good use case for batch.

With batch, here's an example of how to use TextIO to ingest Json using the TableRowJsonCoder ([link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TopWikipediaSessions.java))

There are also many examples of writing output to BigQuery, such as the mobile gaming example ([link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/gaming-example))

If the data is being written to the input files frequently, in other words, if you have a continuous data source you wish to process, then consider ingesting the input to PubSub directly, and using this as the input to a streaming pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We currently have a backlog of json files sitting in GCS ready for processing. But going forward these files will be pulled from various APIs, probably at a reasonably constant rate, though there will be spikes every hour. It would seem logical to use Pub/sub going forward but I guess I will need to process the backlog as a batch job. Having both batch and streaming use cases is why I am choosing Dataflow over Spark, and also because it is fully managed.